# Access build config extra properties set using kotlin DSL

Tags: android, kotlin, dsl

In my android application I am setting some extra properties which I should be able to get via build config.

```
android {
extra.apply {
    set("version", "AN-1.15")
}
//...rest config
}
```

The build config file I get is

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.oads";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "dynamicNativeExoplayerSsaiCommon";
  public static final String FLAVOR_exoplayerVersion = "exoplayer";
  public static final String FLAVOR_common = "common";
}
```

I don't see the version tag in build config.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think those properties come from project properties (which is what you're setting using `extra`). In my project (which is old, so this might have changed), we set them using:

```
android {
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      buildConfigField("String", "version", "AN-1.15")
    }
  }
}
```